# How to get the 'right click + scroll' feature of VistaSwitcher in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, mouse-scroll, application-switcher

When using Windows I use VistaSwitcher to scroll through open windows. I have used Compiz to set Ctrl+Scroll to next and prev windows but I'd (ideally) like something with the ability to see the windows as I scroll.

Many thanks!

James

Comment: Would like to know if you use UNITY environment or GNOME??

Comment: Well before using compiz just know that it is a high end settings control tool. selecting wrong things that have compatibility issues with each other can cause problems specially if you use UNITY environment.The ring-switcher and Shift Switcher wont work even if you enable them in UNITY environment.

Comment: I do indeed use Unity. So neither of those switchers will work in Unity? hmmm...

Comment: Well but in Unity also if you have multiple windows of a particular application open then you can see the pages.

Comment: @Nirmik Did you try it? Of course these plugins work in Unity! And "Compiz" [is not a "high end settings control tool"](http://askubuntu.com/tags/compiz/info) - you should distinguish between Compiz and CCSM ...

Answer (score 0):

In CompizConfig Settings Manager [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] activate the plugins "Ring Switcher" or "Shift Switcher". You can set your preferred shortcuts there, too.

Screenshot of Shift Switcher in action from compiz.org:

[image: shift switcher]

[(More about these plugins on compiz.org.)](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Switcher)

But be aware: *CCSM is an advanced tool. Use with caution. This tool allows you to deeply configure Compiz's settings. Some options may be incompatible with each other. Unless used with care, it is possible to be left with an unusable desktop.*

Comment: Thanks, Ive checked these out but as far as I can see I can only set Alt, Super, Ctrl or Shift to work with the scrolling. Do you know if there's a way to set right click and scroll together?

Comment: AFAIK you can choose more than one key for an action, but not more than one button ..